# Bash while loop containing a rsync command does not work

Tags: bash, ssh, while-loop, rsync

I have the following file containing spaces :

```bash
$ cat /.shareLIST
Archive 1
Archive 2
Archive 3
Archive 4
```

And I have the following `bash` while loop :

```bash
while read share
do
    echo $share
    rsync -Hauv -h -P $server:"$share" $destination/
done < /.shareLIST
```

When executing the script, the loop code is executed only one time instead of four times.

I also noticed this `ssh` process which seems to be launched by the `rsync` command in my while loop :

```bash
# ps -C ssh -o cmd=
ssh -l user mySERVER rsync --server --sender -vulHogDtpre.iLsfxC .......
#
```

I have read on the stackexchange forums that when using a ssh command inside while loop, one needs to use the `ssh -n` to make this work.

EDIT0 : Here is the hexadecimal dump of my `.shareLIST` file :

```bash
# xxd /.shareLIST
0000000: 4172 6368 6976 6520 310a 4172 6368 6976  Archive 1.Archiv
0000010: 6520 320a 4172 6368 6976 6520 330a 4172  e 2.Archive 3.Ar
0000020: 6368 6976 6520 340a                      chive 4.
```

EDIT1 : My quesion is not a duplicate of question [While loop executes only once when using rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24334589/5649639) because there is no explicit ssh command in my loop so I cannot add `-n` as suggested [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334589/while-loop-executes-only-once-when-using-rsync#comment37618669_24334725).
Instead: one solution found by @Inian [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76660146/bash-while-loop-containing-a-rsync-command-does-not-work?noredirect=1#comment135157277_76660146) is to append `< /dev/null` at the end of the `rsync` command to prevent it from swallowing stdin.

In my case, what should I do ?

Comment: I don't see why the loop is executed only once. If the data are exactly as you gave, the loop is executed once for each input line, but since the first word in each input line is `Archive`, the variable `share` is set each time to the same value, i.e. _Archive_.

Comment: I suggest that you turn on tracing (with `set -x`) and post a screenshot, which would support your claim that you get only a single iteration.

Comment: @user1934428 The first occurrence of the echo in the loop shows : `Archive 1`. Then the `rsync` is run and then the loop stops.

Comment: Post the screenshot, including the trace. I have the feeling that the commands in your script are not exactly the same as the ones you posted. Ah, and also show a hex dump of your input file (`xxd ./shareLIST`).

Comment: @user1934428 The loop is only a small part of the original script but added the hex dump you asked in the EDIT0.

Comment: Add `< /dev/null` to the line containing the `rsync` command to prevent ssh from swallowing stdin.

Comment: Did you set `set -e` or `set -o errexit` in you code?  Also, I think you should quote your variables : `$server:$share $destination` --> `"$server:$share" "$destination"`.

Comment: @Grobu I did not use `set -e` nor `set -o errexit`. I did quote my variables in the original version of the script for the ones that might contains white spaces :). Now, I will add quote on the "$share" variable in my question as well.

Comment: @Inian Thanks, I believe that's the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @Inian : There is no reason why an `ssh` invoked by `rsync` is supposed to consume additional standard input. This would at least have to be documented in the rsync man page. My guess is that the loop contains more than just the rsync command shown here, and one of the other commands in the loop is eating the stdin.

Comment: @user1934428 There only one `rsync` command in the original script. BTW : `rsync` runs a remote shell on the destination (here `ssh` by default) to start `rsync --server`. My guess is that this remote shell swallows stdin.

Comment: I checked the man-page for rsync, and they don't say that stdin would be consumed if rsync uses ssh. Therefore, *if* the proposal by Inian works, I would suggest that you ask at [su] (since this is then a better place for this question), why rsync behaves in such an undocumented way. Perhaps you just have a flakey rsync? What does `rsync --version` say? What platform are you on?

Comment: One more idea: If Inian is right with his guess, you can easily reproduce the problem on the command line: Type the `rsync` command manually; **if** rsync is using stdin for serving its ssh, the command would hang, until you type control-c or control-d. But I honestly don't believe that this will be the case.

Comment: @user1934428 Why would the `rsync` developper need to document the `stdin` issues of every possible remote shell ? I'm using `rsync 3.1.2  protocol version 31` on `CentOS 7.9`.

Comment: Because if I implement any utility, and my utility would consume from the outside stdin, this is certainly something in need of documentation. I would have to document that stdin is used, and how it is used. You find this in virtually every man-page of any utility. OTOH, if I use for implementation another utility eating stdin, it is my responsibility to supply an empty stdin for this sub-program. As a programmer, I would get killed by my client if I would do differently.

Comment: Of course `ssh` or `rsh` or `grep` or whatever I am using for writing an utility, may process stdin, but this must not be shown upwards to the people using my utility. The same is true for instance for environment variables. That's why a programmer is providing a specifically constructed environment for any external program being invoked, so surprising side effects are avoided.

Comment: If rsync is eating stdin, surely it would first output something... e.g. a prompt asking the user a question? Seems unlikely it would gratuitously  eat stdin.

Comment: @xpusostomos Strangely I found no prompt nor rsync asking any question.

Comment: To find out if STDIN consumption is part of the issue, you could move your `< /.shareLIST` away from the `while` block : `exec 3< ./shareLIST` and `while read share <&3`.  Also `set -o xtrace` for extended debug info from Bash.